# Split column into 2 column oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a data like this

```
AIN     ACCEPT_TYPE DATE1
91957753    A      04-NOV-14 12.50.31 PM
91957753    R      06-NOV-14 11.18.01 AM
919577      A      04-NOV-14 12.50.31 PM
919577      A      05-NOV-14 11.18.01 AM
```

And look for result like this

```
AIN     ACCEPT_TYPE_1   ACCEPT_TYPE_2   Date_1                  Date_2
91957753    A                 R             04-NOV-14 12.50.31 PM   06-NOV-14 11.18.01 AM
919577      A                 A             04-NOV-14 12.50.31 PM   05-NOV-14 11.18.01 AM
```

Is this possible.? Sorry i'm new to oracle .any help will be much helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple:

```
select AIN,
       max(ACCEPT_TYPE) keep (dense_rank first order by date1) ACCEPT_TYPE_1,
       max(ACCEPT_TYPE) keep (dense_rank first order by date1 desc) ACCEPT_TYPE_2,
       min(DATE1) date_1, 
       max(DATE1) date_2
  from my_table
 group by AIN
```